# Remoting OR wcf service..which is faster?

Tags: wcf

Imagine a pretty complex application where several hundreds of methods are exposed via several interfaces and this is exposed to all the clients over a Tcp channel through .Net remoting.

And if we do the same using WCF service. Lets say we have only .Net Clients here.

So, I was wondering if moving the whole app from Remoting to WCF will have performance hits?

Which is quicker/performance wise?

Does exposing several interfaces(hosting as service)in WCF has any overhead over remoting or maybe the other way around?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized that I don't think that post answers your question very well. Sorry if I pointed you in the wrong direction.

Comment: I would say a most compelling reason to **not** using .NET Remoting is from Microsoft itself: "[.NET Remoting is] a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now be developed using the Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)."

Comment: @Anton your article seems pretty salient to the discussion. I'd wager WCF performance has gotten even better since 2007.

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer: could you provide a link to that "legacy" verbiage?

Comment: @JohnSaunders it's at the top of the page on Remoting here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xws7132e.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Where is your performance place? It is in your single method or systen response or ... ? 
If your performance is in single method, remoting is faster. 
If your performance is in system response, it is depending on your system architecture.